# Display buttons on hover in NSWindow

Tags: button, hover, nswindow

How can I get the buttons (close, minimize, maximize) to hide when the cursor isn't over the window and show themselves when the cursor is.

Basically, I want to duplicate the behavior that Quicktime has.

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass `NSWindow` you can do it with your own buttons and tracking area.